# Setting a rule for outgoing documents and for incoming signed documents - Docusign for Salesforce

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to set up Docusign in Salesforce so that when a document (Quote) goes out, it goes to the Approving Manager first, and then his signature triggers the document to go the the customer.

Once the Quote is completely signed by all parties, I need for several people to receive a copy of the signed document, not just the person who sent it.  I also need the completely executed document to be saved in Salesforce.

This is part of the work flow for the company-wide Quote process in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to provide details of what you've already attempted to get this working.  This seems like a very basic case of using the Routing Order value of Recipient.  Your Approving Manager recipient would be Routing Order 1, other signers all Routing Order 2, and the people who need copies can be Routing Order 3.